# URL keeps returning nil

Tags: swift, url

When using the URL initializer that takes a string, I keep getting back the nil result. Typically this is the case when an invalid or empty string is passed. But I don't see that being the case with my string. Interestingly, I can sucessfully create a NSURL, but not a URL.

When I take that same string and bring it to Playgrounds, I can sucessfully make a URL.

In playgrounds:

```swift
let s = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/ab1234-us/playlists"
let z = URL.init(string: s)
print(z) //works
let a = URL(string: s)
print(a) //works
```

In regular development environment

```swift
let str = master.rawValue + users.rawValue + "/" + user_id + "/" + SpotifyPlaylist.type.searchKey.rawValue
//where str has the same value as s in playgrounds
let myURL = NSURL(string: str)
print(myURL) //works
let a = URL.init(string: str)
print(a) //fails
```

Comment: Yeah, known bug. Crazy, isn't it? You'd think they'd have fixed this... wait, let me check whether it's fixed in 11.4 beta, I'll be right back.

Comment: Actually I can't get your example to fail in 11.3.1 either, sorry. `print(a)` is a URL, not `nil`. Could you try updating your Xcode?

Comment: I should also say, just for completeness, that an expression like `master.rawValue + users.rawValue + "/" + user_id + "/" + SpotifyPlaylist.type.searchKey.rawValue` is _not_ how to make a URL. Construct it out of URLComponents and use proper path appending. Any time you say `+ "/" +` that's a bad smell.